# Issue connecting to ECR using Spinnaker on Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cicd

I installed Spinnaker onto a Kubernetes cluster via Helm. I have tried to add the ECR registry as per the docs and so far not working. I found that the aws cli is missing even though in issue [2394](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2394) it was adding into the Dockerfile, looks like as of master it is included still. Wondering what helm used that was so wrong to not have it?

Am I missing something?

Comment: what docs ? also do you get any error at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update for anyone else who runs into this issue, when Spinnaker is installed using helm it's using an older version of the Halyard container which doesn't have the AWS CLI tool. This seems to be hard to resolve as just updating the values file for helm to the latest version doesn't seem to work and I didn't dig much into the specifics as didn't want to go down that rabbit hole.